# Embedded C/C++: undefined reference of an existing symbol

Tags: c++, c, linker, embedded

I'm having a hard time linking a my code against an Atmel library.

My code uses the function **GetTickCount()** defined in an Atmel Library. My cpp file compiles ok but fails on linking. The library is present during linkage and actually been used by another C file in the process.

- My file **I2C_due.cpp** calls the function **GetTickCount()**.
- The function **GetTickCount()** is present in the library **libsam_sam3x8e_gcc_rel.a** (from **timetick.c**). This is a pre-built file from Atmel.
- The file **wiring.c** (from Arduino) is compiled with my file, has calls to **GetTickCount()** as well, but it is placed inside **libFrameworkArduino.a** before linking.

During linkage, the linker does not complain about calls to **GetTickCount()** from **wiring.c**, but do about my file. If I remove the lib **libsam_sam3x8e_gcc_rel.a** from linker command line, it of course complains about **wiring.c** calls as well. So I'm sure the lib is being used during link (and it is at the end of command line, so the linker parses my file first).

I'm wondering about two things:

1. I'm calling a C function inside a C++ method.
2. Something related to the new C visibility feature.

The **GetTickCount()** is defined inside **timetick.c** embedded in **libsam_sam3x8e_gcc_rel.a**:

```
extern uint32_t GetTickCount( void )
{
    return _dwTickCount ;
}
```

**timetick.h**:

```
extern uint32_t GetTickCount( void ) ;
```

Linker command line:

```
arm-none-eabi-g++ -o .pioenvs/due/firmware.elf -Os -mthumb -mcpu=cortex-m3 \
  -Wl,--gc-sections -Wl,--check-sections -Wl,--unresolved-symbols=report-all \
  -Wl,--warn-common -Wl,--warn-section-align -Wl,--entry=Reset_Handler -u _sbrk \
  -u link -u _close -u _fstat -u _isatty -u _lseek -u _read -u _write -u _exit \
  -u kill -u _getpid -Wl,-T"flash.ld" (many objects).o \
  .pioenvs/due/src/Marlin/HAL/DUE/I2C_due.o (many objects).o -L(many lib dirs) \
  -Wl,--start-group .pioenvs/due/libFrameworkArduinoVariant.a \
  .pioenvs/due/libFrameworkArduino.a -lc -lgcc -lm -lsam_sam3x8e_gcc_rel \
  .pioenvs/due/lib/libWire.a .pioenvs/due/lib/libSPI.a -Wl,--end-group
```

And the error:

```
/home/alex/(longdir)/HAL/DUE/I2C_due.cpp:239: undefined reference to `GetTickCount()'

...

.pioenvs/(longdir)/HAL/DUE/I2C_due.o:/home/alex/(longdir)/HAL/DUE/I2C_due.cpp:344: more undefined references to `GetTickCount()' follow
```

Just a check in the lib:

```
$ nm -s libsam_sam3x8e_gcc_rel.a | grep GetTickCount
GetTickCount in timetick.o
00000001 T GetTickCount
```

Any hint on how can I get my file linked??

Cheers.

Alex.

Comment: Missing `extern "C"`?

Comment: The call is inside a C++ method, I cannot use extern "C"

Comment: Not around the call. Around the declaration.

Comment: yano, you can see the "-lsam_sam3x8e_gcc_rel" in linker command line.

Comment: R.., the timetick.h and timetick.c are part of a library, I'm not suppose to change it.. It can be automatically updated anytime. Of course I can work it around, but I wanna know the "real" issue.

Comment: ah yes, I missed it .. and you're sure `-L(many lib dirs)` contains a path to `libsam_sam3x8e_gcc_rel.a`? If those are relative paths, might be worth adding an absolute path to where `libsam_sam3x8e_gcc_rel.a` is just to be sure.

Answer (score 1):

Analyzing R.. comment, I figured out my mistake.

There is not allowed to place a call to C function inside a C++ function. 
That's the reason we use the **extern "C"** before the function declaration.

I had to create a .c and .h files and use the **extern "C"** in the .h.

**teste.c**:

```
uint32_t MiliS()
{
    return GetTickCount();
}
```

**teste.h**:

```
extern "C" uint32_t MiliS();
```

That way we can call **MiliS()** from a .cpp file and it will be a wrapper to **GetTickCount()**

Comment: A good discussion about **extern "C"**: 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1041866/in-c-source-what-is-the-effect-of-extern-c

Comment: Rather than modifying teste.h (which breaks using it from C), you should put `extern "C" {}` around the `#include`.

Comment: Thanks again @R..
Actually I wrapped the **extern "C"** with compilation flag **__cplusplus**. Same results.. Thanks for guiding me to the solution.

Comment: One more documentation about the topic: https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/mixing-c-and-cpp